# Iterating over Boost fusion::vector

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-fusion

I'm trying to iterate over a boost::fusion vector using:

```
typedef typename fusion::result_of::begin<T>::type t_iter;
  std::cout << distance(begin(t), end(t)) << std::endl;
  for(t_iter it = begin(t); it != end(t); next(it)){
    std::cout<<deref(it)<<std::endl;
  }
```

The distance cout statement gives me a finite length (2), however the loop seems to run indefinitely.

Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just iterate a *Fusion* vector like that, the type for each iterator may be different than the previous one (and usually is). I guess that's why you don't have `it = next(it)` in your code, it would give a compilation error.

You could use `boost::fusion::for_each` for this, together with a function object that prints each element to the standard output:

```
struct print
{
    template< typename T >
    void operator()( T& v ) const
    {
        std::cout << v;
    }
};

...

boost::fusion::for_each( t, print() );
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I want to assign each element of the vector a value. I assume I should do something similar?

Comment: @arlogb: While you could do something similar, it's probably easier to just generate a new compatible sequence with the new values and assign it to the target sequence.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I don't know how many values I want to assign till runtime, so whereas I'd use something like `push_back` on a `std::vector<T>` here I'm still a little lost as to how to assign values.

Comment: @arlogb: _Fusion Sequences_ are typed beasts, you can't have a dynamic sequence. That is, the result of `push_back` on a _Sequence_ results in a **new** _Sequence_.

Comment: OK, maybe I haven't phrased my problem very well. Essentially I'm expecting to get something like `fusion::vector<int, int, int>` or `fusion::vector<int, double>` passed to a (templated) function and would like to fill whatever I get with some values.

Answer (score 2):

`fusion` is a wonderful library, and you should now that it is really different from what you use in every day C++ programs in multiple ways, it merge the power of compile time meta programming with runtime, for that you should now that there is no type that can handle all items in a `fusion` container. What this means? it means that `result_of::begin<T>::type` is not always a match of `next(it)` so you can't use `fusion` iterators in a `for` like that.

The obvious problem in your code is that you ignore return value of `next` and it will cause your code to run forever but you can't use it in `it = next(it)`, since their type may vary!!

So what you should do?? You should use `boost::fusion::for_each` for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

`next` doesn't actually advance the iterator, it just returns the next one.

This can be seen in the docs, as the function `next` takes a constant argument, meaning it can't possibly actually modify the iterator:

```
template<
    typename I
    >
typename result_of::next<I>::type next(I const& i);
                                         ^^^^^
```

Comment: Ah yes, you're quite right. Is there a way to advance the iterator then? I see the `advance` method also takes a `const` so I assume that doesn't move the iterator either.

Comment: @arlogb, Advancing the same iterator gives you the problem discussed in K-Ballo's answer. I would suggest the general solution boost provides for iterating the entire vector that is `for_each`, which is nicely demonstrated for you in the very same answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside the loop you are [dereferencing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/iterator/functions/deref.html) your iterator. When you apply `next` on it, it means nothing and that's why your loop runs forever.

Comment: @JesseGood dereferencing your *iterator* I meant. Thanks!

Comment: @arlogb actually the answer (wrong usage of `next`) was given by K-ballo and chris