# How to fill boost::fusion::vector at runtime?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

Firstly, apologies for the similarity to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094535/iterating-over-boost-fusionvector), but I don't think I asked the right thing.

I have a method:

```
template <typename T>
void some_method( T &t)
{...}
```

which takes a type `fusion::vector<T1, T2, T3, ..., Tn>` to be determined at runtime - e.g. `vector<int, double>` in one call and `vector<int, double, int>` in another.

I want to fill this vector dynamically with something like:

```
int blah = 5;
for(int i = 0; i<size(t); i++){
at_c<i>(t) = blah;
}
```

This doesn't work since at_c expects a `const`.

I've tried other stuff (see the previous question) but still can't work out how to achieve this.

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: What is `blah`? A straight for-loop will never work, because `blah` has to have a different type at each iteration (you need to write a recursive template function). Can you provide a few examples of the way that you are representing the values to be inserted?

Comment: I'm assuming that the values that will be inserted will be appropriately cast to the right type. For sake of argument you could imagine `blah` is an `int`.

Comment: They will not be determined at _runtime_, they will be determined at _compile-time_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Mankarse specified correctly, you can't use `fusion` containers in a `for` loop and that's because `fusion` containers are all about `tuple` and each element may have different type from other elements, all functions that iterate through a `fusion` container are actually a couple of functions and usually implemented as `template` or overloaded functions. So in order to initialize a `fusion` container from a `vector` you should have multiple functions (or simply a template that will be compiled to multiple classes or functions) that all have access to that vector(or at least an iterator from the `vector` and an state variable that can increased for each call). So you have 2 options:

1) Use boost::fusion::fold:

```
template< class StdIteratorT >
struct initialize_fusion_container_from_std_iterator {
    typedef StdIteratorT    result_type;

    template< class T >
    StdIteratorT operator()( StdIteratorT i, T& val ) {
        val = *i;
        return ++i;
    }
};
void use_fold_demo() {
    int p1[] = {4, 5, 6};
    fusion::vector<int, double, int> fv;
    std::vector<int> sv2( p1, p1 + _countof(p1) );
    fusion::fold( fv, sv2.begin(),
    initialize_fusion_container_from_std_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>() );
}
```

2) Write a function that recursively call itself with next item of the container(remember syntax of this function is like recursive functions but it is not recursive at all):

```
// this will be called when we reach end of the fusion container(FIBeginT==FIEndT)
template< class FIBeginT, class FIEndT, class StdIteratorT >
void set_fusion_iterator( FIBeginT b, FIEndT e, StdIteratorT i, boost::mpl::true_ )
{
}
// this will be called when FIBeginT != FIEndT
template< class FIBeginT, class FIEndT, class StdIteratorT >
void set_fusion_iterator( FIBeginT b, FIEndT e, StdIteratorT i, boost::mpl::false_ )
{
    *b = *i;
    set_fusion_iterator( fusion::next(b), e, ++i,
        fusion::result_of::equal_to<
            typename fusion::result_of::next<FIBeginT>::type, FIEndT >() );
}

void recursive_function_demo() {
    typedef fusion::vector<int, double, int>    my_fusion_vector;

    int p1[] = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> sv1( p1, p1 + _countof(p1) );
    fusion::vector<int, double, int> fv;
    set_fusion_iterator( fusion::begin(fv), fusion::end(fv), sv1.begin(),
        fusion::result_of::equal_to<
            typename fusion::result_of::end<my_fusion_vector>::type,
            typename fusion::result_of::begin<my_fusion_vector>::type>() );
}
```

As you see second case is much more complicated, but if you understand its logic you can use it to do anything with `fusion` containers, so the choice is all yours!!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [boost::fusion::for_each](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/for_each.html):

```
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/container.hpp>

struct F {
    F(int blah): blah(blah){}
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const {
        t = blah;
    }
    int blah;
};

template <typename T>
void some_method(T &t)
{
    boost::fusion::for_each(t, F(6));
}

int main() {
    boost::fusion::vector<int, double, int> idi;
    some_method(idi);
    boost::fusion::vector<int, double> id;
    some_method(id);
}
```

In an attempt to demystify the `for_each`, here is some mostly equivalent code that uses numerical indices instead:

```
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/container.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence.hpp>

template<typename T, int N, int End>
struct some_method_impl {
    void operator()(T& t) const {
        int blah = 6;
        boost::fusion::at_c<N>(t) = blah;
        some_method_impl<T, N+1, End>()(t);
    }
};

template<typename T, int N>
struct some_method_impl<T,N,N> {
    void operator()(T& t) const {}
};


template <typename T>
void some_method(T &t)
{
    some_method_impl<T,0,boost::fusion::result_of::size<T>::type::value>()(t);
}

int main() {
    boost::fusion::vector<int, double, int> idi;
    some_method(idi);
    boost::fusion::vector<int, double> id;
    some_method(id);
}
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Actually you're quite right though, I should have been more specific about `blah`...
It is a `vector<int>` and I want to map a value from this `blah` to the fusion::vector. Is it possible with your suggested method?

Comment: @arlogb: Yes, [zip](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/concepts/random_access_sequence.html) the sequence together with a set of indices, and then use the indices to index in to the vector during the `for_each`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

This is similar to the above case using 
     boost::fusion::for_each
.

But faster when i < size(t)  than the above.

usage

```
main(){
  boost::fusion::vector<int,double,std::string,char> vec(9 ,2.2 ,"aaa" ,'b');
  std::cout << at_n_dynamic<double>(vec, 1) << std::endl; //=> 2.2
}
```

body

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>    
template<typename V>
struct fusion_at_n_functor
{
   mutable int i;
   int n;
   mutable V value;
   fusion_at_n_functor(int _n):i(0),n(_n){}
   void operator()(const V & t) const
   { if(i==n){value=t;} i++;}  
   template<typename T>
   void operator()(const T & t) const
   { i++;}
};

template <typename First,typename Last,typename AtN > void
at_n_dynamic_fusion_impl(First i,Last last,AtN &atn,boost::mpl::true_ ){}
template <typename First,typename Last,typename AtN > void
at_n_dynamic_fusion_impl(First i,Last last,AtN &atn,boost::mpl::false_ ){  
  if(atn.i == atn.n ){atn(boost::fusion::deref(i));}
  else{
    atn(boost::fusion::deref(i));
    at_n_dynamic_fusion_impl(boost::fusion::next(i),last,atn,
           boost::fusion::result_of::equal_to<
             typename boost::fusion::result_of::next<First>::type,Last>  ());}
}

template <typename Ret,typename Sequence>  Ret
 at_n_dynamic(Sequence & seq, int n){ 
   fusion_at_n_functor<Ret> atn(n);
#if 0 
  // enabling this if is same to the above case of boost::fusion::for_each 
   boost::fusion::for_each(seq, atn);
#else
  // this recursion loop stop at n. but boost::fusion::for_each stop at last
   at_n_dynamic_fusion_impl(boost::fusion::begin(seq),boost::fusion::end(seq) ,atn,
         boost::fusion::result_of::equal_to<
           typename boost::fusion::result_of::begin<Sequence>::type,
           typename boost::fusion::result_of::end<Sequence>::type>());    
#endif
    return atn.value;}
```

This is 
 copy of boost-users ML my post 
http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2012/08/75493.php 
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/niitsuma/20120803/1343979718