# How to use vector in boost

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I tried following example from [boost doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/vector.html), but not sure what header should be included. Had tried the headers in the doc but still reporting: `error: 'vector' was not declared in this scope`

```
vector<int, float> v(12, 5.5f);
std::cout << at_c<0>(v) << std::endl;
std::cout << at_c<1>(v) << std::endl;
```

Btw, I haven't installed boost on my PC yet, just using [the online IDE](http://ideone.com/7jJkvj).

Comment: you have to specify which `vector` it is supposed to be. I guess it is not the `std::vector`...

Comment: [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be included in your question itself.

Comment: @tobi303 It is the vector in boost C++ libraries, I had posted the link to the boost vector document in my question.

Comment: @Deqing Looks like you're looking for the [`boost::numeric::ublas::vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.html), it's all pretty well documented in their sample.

Comment: Thanks @πάνταῥεῖ. I guess it is not. The vector I'm looking for is a container that can store different types of data. Looks like it is called `Fusion sequence container`, but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Quit being so rude please. That documentation page (which the OP himself linked to in the question) doesn't make even a _single_ mention of which namespaces to use. To which "documentations" are you referring? It's telling that you've posted and deleted _two_ completely wrong answers already. So why are you up on your high horse with this guy?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I learned my lessons. Though I'm not sure that rolling back my edits really helps to improve the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The edit didn't help to improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This documentation is really unclear, but **[the full name of the type is `boost::fusion::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096320/560648)**.

That sample code seems to presume both `#include`s and a `using boost::fusion::vector`. [The Quick Start for *Boost.Fusion*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/quick_start.html) makes the same mistake. It seems like whoever wrote the documentation has some bad habits.

Comment: Thanks. Finally get the example running, need another `using boost::fusion::at_c` and `#include`s as well.

Comment: @Deqing: It may be worth raising this as an issue on whatever the Boost.Fusion mailing list is.